# How to deactivate sendfile() in Django runserver

Tags: python, django, apache, nginx

I am running a Django development environment using Vagrant/VirtualBox.

I am using [runserver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-runserver) for my local testing. However, I have encountered this bug: **https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/virtualbox.html**

Thisis a VirtualBox bug related to `sendfile` which can result in corrupted or non-updating files. It's a simple fix, I just need to deactivate sendfile the webserver running.

In Nginx this would be:

```
sendfile off;
```

In Apache this would be:

```
EnableSendfile Off
```

How can I deactivate `sendfile` in `runserver`?